# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Authentication Required

Tags: authentication, smtp

i want to send mail to  more than 1000 users of my web application.I am purchasing a new smtp service plan. i am using the following code for sending email.

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
  message.From = new MailAddress("info@mydomain.com", "Web Administration Team");
  message.To.Add(new MailAddress("user1@gmail.com"));
  message.Subject = "test";
  message.Body = "Email Content";
  message.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("domain.smtp.com", 2525);           
  smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;            
  smtp.EnableSsl = false;
  smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@domain.com","password");           
  smtp.Send(message);
```

But i am getting the following error message.

**Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Authentication Required. Please contact support (support@smtp.com) if you are having trouble authenticating successfully**

Answer (score 8):

The SMTP server requires a username and password for authentication, to ensure that only customers send spam through it.

See http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.2.aspx for how to authenticate when using System.Net.Mail.

Comment: +1 for "to ensure that only customers send spam" (-: